# JQuery Add Text Element To Nav When It Reaches Top Of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navbar, nav

I am making a website with a stick navbar. I would like to add the text elemnent "▲" to the left of the navbar when it reaches the top of the webpage and "sticks". I would also like to remove the element when the navbar "unsticks" (leaves the top of the webpage). Below is the JQuery and HTML I am using:

```js
var distance = $('div').offset().top,
  $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
  if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
    $("#nav").prepend("<li style=\"float: left;\" id=\"navSymbol\"><a href=\"#\">▲</a></li>");
  } else {
    $("#navSymbol").remove();

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav" class="sticky">
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CAPABILITIES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">RFQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
```

However when I scroll the JQuery just inserts a million symbols into the navbar whenever I scroll instead of just one when it reaches the top like this:

[image: Screen Shot Of Error]

This is very frustrating so I help someone can help.

Edit:

The complete code is below, not sure if it helps :) (It is not responsive yet so doesn't look right without being expanded)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,400,500,700,900&display=swap');
@keyframes shadow-pulse {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 0px black;
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10vw black;
  }
}

#headerTriangle {
  font-size: 6vw !important;
  animation: shadow-pulse 3s infinite;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8vw;
}

.headerText {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5vw;
  padding: 2vw 0vw 2vw 0vw;
}

#nav {
  padding-top: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline;
}

#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

#nav a:hover {
  animation: shadow-pulse 2s 1;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Handmade Studios</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Alex Hawking">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!--Fonts-->

</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <h1 id="headerTriangle">▲</h1>
    <h1 class="headerText" style="font-weight: 500;">Hello World</h1>
    <h1 class="headerText" style="font-weight: 300; font-size: 3vw !important;">This is some random stuff I've made.
    </h1>
  </div>

  <ul id="nav" class="sticky">
    <li id="navSymbol"><a href="#">▲</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CAPABILITIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">RFQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>





  <div style="height: 100vw;"></div>



  <!--Scripts-->

  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    console.log($('div:last').offset().top)
    var distance = $('div').offset().top,
      $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function() {

      if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {

        $("#navSymbol").hide();
      } else {
        $("#navSymbol").show();

      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:300,400,500,700,900&display=swap');
@keyframes shadow-pulse {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 0px black;
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10vw black;
  }
}

#headerTriangle {
  font-size: 6vw !important;
  animation: shadow-pulse 3s infinite;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8vw;
}

.headerText {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5vw;
  padding: 2vw 0vw 2vw 0vw;
}

#nav {
  padding-top: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline;
}

#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

#nav a:hover {
  animation: shadow-pulse 2s 1;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Handmade Studios</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Alex Hawking">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!--Fonts-->

</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <h1 id="headerTriangle">▲</h1>
    <h1 class="headerText" style="font-weight: 500;">Hello World</h1>
    <h1 class="headerText" style="font-weight: 300; font-size: 3vw !important;">This is some random stuff I've made.
    </h1>
  </div>

  <ul id="nav" class="sticky">
    <li id="navSymbol"><a href="#">▲</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CAPABILITIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">RFQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>





  <div style="height: 100vw;"></div>



  <!--Scripts-->

  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    console.log($('#navSymbol').offset().top)
    var distance = $('#navSymbol').offset().top,
      $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function() {
    console.log($window.scrollTop());
      if ($window.scrollTop() <= 0) {

        $("#navSymbol").show();
      } else {
        $("#navSymbol").hide();

      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for your reply, however adding this just adds the symbol, nothing changes or anything. As I said I would like it to add the symbol when the navbar is at the top and remove it when it leaves the top. :)

Comment: @AlexHawking I have updated my coding. please check. if any problem let me know.

Comment: I reinserted your js and it now removes the symbol when it is not at the top of the page but does not re add it. I will also add my css to the question to see if that will help anyone.

Comment: @AlexHawking can you  please `Run code snippet` you will find that re-add symbol when it is top

Comment: It does work when I run it there and it works but not when it is on my webpage. Would it help if I shared the complete code, could be some sort css or something messing it up?

Comment: @AlexHawking I have updated my coding please check is working for you? if any problem let me know.

Comment: If you check the snippet the code does not work, sorry

Comment: @AlexHawking can you check in full page mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197263/discussion-between-alex-hawking-and-mohammad-ali-rony).